# URL fingerprint caching on Amazon S3

Tags: url, caching, mod-rewrite, amazon-s3, fingerprint

I have a bucket on Amazon S3 where I keep files that sometimes change but I want to use maximum caching on them, so I want to use URL fingerprinting to invalidate the cache.

I use the "last modified" date of the files for the fingerprint, and the html page requesting the S3 files always knows each file's fingerprint.

Now, I realize that I could use the fingerprint in the query string, like so:

```
http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/myFile.jpg?v=1310476099061
```

but the query string is not always enough for some proxies or older browsers to invalidate the cache, and some proxies and browsers don't even cache it if it contains a query string. That's why I want to keep the fingerprint in the actual URL, like one of these:

```
http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/myFile-1310476099061.jpg
http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/1310476099061/myFile.jpg
http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/myFile.jpg/1310476099061
etc
```

Any of these URLs would be perfect for requesting the myFile.jpg, but I want it all to be remapped to the `http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/myFile.jpg` file. That is, I only want the URL to change so the browser will think that it is a new file and get a fresh file which it will cache for a year. When I upload a new version of that file, the fingerprint is automatically updated.

Now here is my question: Is there any way to rewrite the url so that a request for a URL like`http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/myFile-xxxxxx.jpg` will serve the `http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/myFile.jpg` file on Amazon S3? Or are there any other workarounds that will still keep the file cached? Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're stuck with the version in the querystring. There is no way to rewrite the urls on S3 without actually changing the filename.

Comment: That's too bad. Although, I think I'll just upload the file with the fingerprint in the file name and delete the old one via a script, that should have the same effect. Thanks.